# How do you type Unicode characters using hexadecimal codes?

Tags: keyboard, unicode, characters

This is in Windows, but answers for other operating systems can be handy to others.

Most guides say something to the effect of "hold down the Alt key and type in the code on the keypad".  This works fine for decimal codes (like 65 for 'A'), but not for [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) codes (like [U+0041](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0041/) for 'A').

Some applicatons provide other facilities that will allow hexadecimal Unicode character codes to be typed and then transformed.  Word allows you to type the code (such as 200f) and then convert it to Unicode by typing Alt-X.

I'm looking for a general method of doing this that will work with the standard input.

Comment: *This works fine for unicode characters that don't include hex chars A through F.* should read: *for decimal codes*. There are plenty of hexadecimal numbers that don't use A-F. Like 10, which is not ten then...

Comment: That's useless to me when I need to type a u+23AF.

Comment: My point is: you cannot type things like u+0041 (hex 41, decimal 65) using the numeric keypad either (as one would then need to type 65 rather than 41) -- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0041 So, using the Alt-trick *works fine for decimal codes, but not for hexadecimal codes*.

Comment: @Will: the "alt+NN..." method expects *decimal*, not hex notation of the character position. Unicode uses hex. So if you want to type what Unicode represents as "U+23AF" you need to convert hex==23AF into decimal==9135, and then type "alt+9135". That's the *only* general method there is on offer. ***But:*** You wanted character may still not appear as expect in the text field or document, if your currently selected font does not have the "U+23AF" place filled (or if it is not a Unicode font in the first place!).

Comment: @Arjan: you do not type ***hex*** chars with the "alt+nnn" method. You do only type ***decimal*** character codes. That's why you cannot type even straight "U+1234" strings (which do not contain any of your loathed "a-f" characters) into your numeric keypad as "alt+1234", but you need to convert hex==1234 into dec==4660 and then type "alt+4660" before you (**MAY**) get what you want. So your statement "using the Alt-trick does not work for hexdecimal codes" nails the problem exactly, but you missed to understand it yourself :-)

Comment: And for those who came here looking to disable `Control + Shift + u` this is discussed [here](https://superuser.com/q/358749/96867).

Comment: See also [How to type special characters in Linux?](https://superuser.com/q/59418/150988).

Comment: the `code + ALT+X` method does not work for me

Answer (score 24, accepted):

harrymc's answer is good, providing you're able/allowed to change the registry settings.

If not, you can use the Windows Calculator Accessory to convert from hexadecimal to decimal.  The default mode won't do this: XP and Vista have a "Scientific mode, whereas Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10 have a "Programmer" mode.

Select **Hex** base, and then type in your hexadecimal number.  Then change to **Dec** base to see the equivalent value in decimal.  That's the number you need to type into your numeric keypad while holding down the **Alt** key.

This [might depend on](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm) the input language, and you might need to prefix a zero to the decimal value.

Comment: you can also calculate with `set /a` in a command window ;-). To convert hex=4321 into decimal, just type `set /a 4*16*16*16+3*16*16+2*16+1` and the result will show up as 17185

Comment: Alternatively, `set /a 0x4321` will also display 17185.

Comment: The answer is misleading, because it does not mention that a leading zero is needed when using a decimal number outside the Ascii range (> 127). If you want to type U+23AF and therefore convert 23AF to decimal, 9135, and then try using Alt 9135, you get “»” (U+00BB). You need to to type Alt 09135 (using the numpad) to get the right character.

Comment: The method using decimal numbers depends on “input language” (as a Microsoft concept), so the results vary by system and program. For example, in most Windows programs, when the system language has been set to English or other Western language, only Windows Latin 1 characters can be typed this way. Any Alt 0n for n > 255 will then work “modulo 256”, i.e. with n reduced to range 0...255 by dividing by 256 and taking the remainder.

Comment: Just like @Jukka mentioned, [the page I linked to in my answer](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm) also suggests you'd need to prefix a zero, and that it depends on the input language.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, I have, for years, misunderstood that Alt+nnnn required four digits, and could never understand why Unicode decimal values >999 wouldn't work.  It's because Alt+nnnn is _really_ Alt+0nnn ... Alt+0nnnn.  I could kiss you.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Alt+0nnn (0-255) inputs a character from the system's ANSI codepage (e.g. 1252). The value entered is modulo 256 as mentioned above. Alt+nnn (0-255), without a leading zero, inputs a character from the system's OEM codepage (e.g. 437 or 850). However, the first 31 codes aren't the normal ASCII control characters, but are instead the glyphs that were displayed for these characters on 1980s PCs running DOS. In the Windows API, the latter corresponds to using the `MB_USEGLYPHCHARS` flag when decoding bytes to Unicode via `MultiByteToWideChar`.

Comment: this does not work - as other mentioned, it depends on selected codepage. Alt+0nnnn worked for me only in Word, anywhere else it fails. Note that the answer has many upvotes and marked as accepted, thus it is very misleading for people searching for the answer and trying hard to replicate your solution which simply does not work.

Answer (score 48):

Found this in [How to enter Unicode characters in Microsoft Windows](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm) :

> I tested this on Windows XP and
> Windows 2003. This method works
> regardless of any of your language
> settings, but is the most cumbersome
> to type:
>
> 1. Press and hold down the Alt key.
> 2. Press the + (plus) key on the numeric keypad.
> 3. Type the hexidecimal unicode value.
> 4. Release the Alt key.
>
> Alas, this appears to require a
> registry setting. It was already set
> on my computer, but some readers
> report that this method didn't work
> for them, and this is probably why. If
> you don't know what the registry is,
> please don't try this. Under
> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method`, set EnableHexNumpad to "1".
> If you have to add it, set the type to
> be REG_SZ.

You should log off then log on after this registry change (you shouldn't need to reboot).

Comment: if I don't know what the registry is, then I don't know how to try neither.

Comment: If you don't know what the registry is, you shouldn't ever touch it.  Ask someone you know for help.

Comment: +1 but a couple of things: (i)in Both Firefox and IE if the hex code you're trying to type contains a leeter corresponding to the Alt+[letter] shortcut for a menu, the menu drops down and you don't get your character (this break E&F on both, A on IE and B on Firefox, notepad works fine as does the winkey+R "run" box) ; (ii)REG_SZ may appear in the right-click new entry menu as "Registry String"

Comment: Is this supposed to work in all applications? I got it to work in notepad, notepad++, Firefox and even Excel, but not in Word, Outlook, PowerPoint nor Lync. This is on W7.

Comment: @DidierL: I would guess that it would work on applications that don't misuse keyboard functions.

Comment: In fact in those applications it ignores the + and it only takes decimal values. But I can't get the decimal form to work in other applications, and it's annoying to have 2 different methods with 2 different values. I'm surprised this doesn't work properly in all MS Office applications.

Comment: @DidierL: Office is not the world's most orderly designed software. If you are looking for a general method, I found the [UnicodeInput utility](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/unicodeinput/) and also the article [standard ways to enter Unicode characters](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm).

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking into the standard ways quite a lot recently, and I'd prefer to avoid the utility (likely to work but I'm not sure I will still be allowed to use it even at short-term). I was just hoping to have a confirmation of whether it should work in Office (2013).

Comment: Hi harrymc. How do I type in letters contained in hex? example:  `"" = &#x1F449; ` - after I hit `F` alt menu command gets executed on windows. It doesn't fly with conversion to decimal (128073) not adding leading zeroes.

Comment: Some of the letters that trigger browser menus while Alt is held down don't do so when the browser is in full screen mode.  Hit F11 before and after typing the Alt code.  Not nice but it works.

Answer (score 17):

On Mac OS X: open International in System Preferences, and in Input Menu select "Unicode Hex Input" to add this option to the input menu. Sounds obvious, but this is well hidden in the long list of languages, between Ukrainian and Vietnamese. When selected, hold down Option and type the 4 digit hex code.

Also on OS X: Calculator can be set to Programmer mode (Cmd-3), which allows for entering decimal, octal and hexadecimal codes, which are then displayed as ASCII or Unicode. However, Copy will give one the code, not the character equivalent(s). Anyone?

(For Windows, see [How to enter Unicode characters in Microsoft Windows](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm); for other input methods see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#Hex_input).)

And here on Super User:

- [Insert Unicode characters via the keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/47420/insert-unicode-characters-via-the-keyboard)
- [Typing strange letters ¿w/o numpad?](https://superuser.com/questions/55502/typing-strange-letters-w-o-numpad)
- [How to type special characters in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/59418/how-to-type-special-characters-in-linux)

And to go into extremes:

- [How do I create Unicode smilies like ٩(•̮̮̃•̃)۶](https://superuser.com/questions/52671/how-do-i-create-unicode-smilies-like)

Answer (score 9):

In Ubuntu (and variants thereof, like LinuxMint) you can enter Unicode values by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> followed by the Unicode value and Enter, for example:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> then Enter yields:

Text: ☺
Screenshot: [image]

You might be able to couple this with AutoHotkey for easier input, or *possible* input in Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately it only works in GTK+ applications.

Comment: You can also hold down Ctrl-Shift while typing the code, which avoids having to press Enter afterwards.

Comment: I have found a better solution:

You can add accent marks to any preceding character using Unicode combining diacritical marks.


Unicode 0301 - 0308 are useful for Pinyin.

for example: "a" + [ctrl][shift][u] + 0301 [return] -> á.

The pinyin list: ó -> 0301;
ò -> 0300;
ō -> 0304;
ŏ -> 0306;
ö -> 0308;

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character#Unicode_ranges

Answer (score 9):

I have written a small AutoHotkey based [Unicode Input tool](http://granjow.net/unicode-input.html) because I did not find a better solution. You can insert unicode characters with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

[image: Unicode dialog]

Basically, it converts the entry to a unicode character and “types” it at cursor position.

It does not support 6-digit unicode characters. Also, if you have an input field where all text is selected on focus loss, all text will be overwritten (I think I remember an old Firefox version showed this behaviour).

As a reference, here the [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) source if you want to compile it by yourself:

```
#SingleInstance force
#Persistent
;Menu, Tray, icon, unicode.ico
Menu, Tray, nostandard ; Put the following menu items on top (default: bottom)
Menu, Tray, add, Info, InfoHandler, -10
Menu, Tray, add
Menu, Tray, standard ; Add default menu items at the bottom
return

InfoHandler:
MsgBox Press Shift+Ctrl+U to get an entry field for unicode points (see decodeunicode.org for a list).`n`nAuthor: Simon A. Eugster <simon.eu@gmail.com> / granjow.net
return

+^u::
InputBox, codepoint, Unicode code point, U+
if not ErrorLevel
    Send {U+%codepoint%}
return
```

Comment: To make it easier just do this: `!x::send "^+{left 3}^x{" A_Clipboard "}"`
to use it:

1. type the unicode like `U+20AC`
2. press Alt+X
3. watch in awe how your euro sign just pops into existance.

This assumes Autohotkey v2. If using v1 just force an expression on the send command.

Answer (score 3):

## Linux (including Qt/KDE applications)

As JMD mentioned, you can hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>, type `u1f4a9`, and release in order to type U+1F4A9 in GTK+ applications (including GNOME programs, Firefox, Chromium, and LibreOffice, even under KDE). Some programs also support typing in sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in Qt applications (including KDE programs, Mathematica, and VLC). For BMP characters, there is a Unicode IBus input method. To enable, open IBus preferences and add the "Other - unicode (m17n)" input method (the two packages **ibus-m17n** and **ibus-qt4** must be installed). When the cursor is in a text area, activate the input method (using the IBus toolbar or the keyboard shortcut). While active, the input method lets you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> followed by 4 hex digits, to input the corresponding Unicode character. This only works for BMP characters, though.

(Tested under Ubuntu.)

Comment: Doesn't work on KDE for me..

Comment: where can i find the IBus preferences?

Answer (score 2):

It also depends where you want to use the special characters. With MS Office apps, you don't have to resort to knowing the ASCII codes for certain characters -- for example, to type a diaresis (i.e., the two dots you see above some characters in words such as naïve), in Word/Outlook/etc you can hit Ctrl + ':' (i.e., Ctrl+Shift+;) followed by 'i'.

There's a list of shortcuts available at http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/General/InsertSpecChars.htm ... just scroll down to "International Characters".

I don't know whether any non-Office apps support similar shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10, you can hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> to open an emoji browser:

[image: Windows 10 emoji picker]

As you can see in the above image, you can also search by simply typing.

Perhaps not exactly what you're asking, but if like me, you were looking for an easy way to type odd Unicode characters instead of using a search engine or reference table all the time, this might work for you.

Comment: Just ... why???

Comment: This one was more helpful than I expected, as (in Windows 11 at least) I am able to choose symbols as well. While this doesn't answer the question, the "recent" part of the symbols section solves my problem (I only searched for a hex version of unicode symbol inserts because I hoped it would be easier to remember the hex version of the various symbols I use every now and then... with this I don't need to remember them anymore)

Answer (score 2):

## Windows - type the character code in hexadecimal

Here is how to type any Unicode character, taking as example the [Euro sign](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm) `€` (Unicode character `U+20AC`). **It works only if the Windows Registry is first modified** as described at the end of this answer:

**Press the keys <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>**

Step by step:

- Press and hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.
- Press the <kbd>+</kbd> (plus) key on the numeric keypad.
- Type each character of the hexadecimal Unicode value in sequence: <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd>.
- Release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

The example above succeeded in Windows 10, but has proved to work in many versions.

**Here is how to change the Windows registry**:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, type `regedit.exe` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the registry editor
- Position on the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method` on the left panel. To position on it, you may simply copy/paste the key name in the search field and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- On the right panel, add a new Value of type `String` (menu Edit > New > String Value), type the name `EnableHexNumpad`, double-click it, set its value data to `1` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

EDIT: you may need to restart your PC (see comments).

PS: for information, one **list of hexadecimal Unicode values** can be found at https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/index.htm.

Comment: worked for me after restarting the PC (maybe logout is also enough)

Answer (score 1):

For the lazy ones, following the [correct answer from harrymc](https://superuser.com/a/59458/137964), you can use the command below in the CMD shell to directly edit the registry:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method" /v EnableHexNumpad /t REG_SZ /d 1
```

Also remember (as noted by *harrymc*) a logoff or reboot might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Firefox on Windows 10 typing for example `»` which has Unicode character U+00BB.

- Hold down <kbd>ALT</kbd> (and still hold)
- Press <kbd>+</kbd>
- Hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and then type <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> (leading zeroes can be left out)
- Release <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>

> Using the additional <kbd>CTRL</kbd> prevents the menu bar to be activated.

Comment: Is it literally pressing "`+`"? Not just `Alt` + `Ctrl` (two keys/modifiers)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen These are two modifiers, but not activated at the same time, Not using CTRL may invoke a context menu. So it depends on the current application. This answer is quite old and I did not use Firefox since, anymore. So it may have changed meanwhile.