# Key for 'ë' , e with a diaeresis, in windows

Tags: keyboard, characters, ascii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you type Unicode characters using hexadecimal codes?](https://superuser.com/questions/13086/how-do-you-type-unicode-characters-using-hexadecimal-codes)

Is it possible to generate this symbol  'ë'  i.e. e with a diaeresis from the keyboard in windows?

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/13086/how-do-you-type-unicode-characters-using-hexadecimal-codes and http://superuser.com/questions/47420/insert-unicode-characters-via-the-keyboard

Comment: This is not a duplicate, you don't seriously expect me to learn the unicode encoding of whatever character is not on my keyboard... (maybe 10 years ago) there must be some combination of compose key that will result in this symbol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hold down <kbd>ALT</kbd>, and type <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> on the key pad on your keyboard. When you release <kbd>ALT</kbd>, it should appear.

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>

ë

Check http://www.asciitable.com, or the ASCII table of your choice for the ASCII codes you can type in.

Comment: I've been using such codes since the middle 80's, where those codes were part of the original 256-characters. But the uppercase ones were not part of this original list, so we had to wait until Windows came out with a more international one. Under Linux, you can use the compose key to have any accent on any character, uppercase or lower case, in a uniform way. Much easier to learn than the numerical codes.

Answer (score 4):

You mean **ë** ??
Just press **alt+0235** .. And voila!!

For more, Go to MS Word, **Insert > Symbols**, then iterate through various fonts for thousands of symbols.. 
Enjoy.. ^_^

Answer (score 3):

You have several choices.

Using alt+number, picking it from character map, etc.
For me, I simply switch to US-International keyboard.

In Vista:

- control panel
- regional and language options
- keyboards and languages
- change keyboards
- add
- English (United States)

After you switch to it, you can enter that by typing <kbd>"</kbd> and <kbd>e</kbd>.

You can switch by selecting through the language bar or by binding it to a specific combination of keys.

This might be an overkill if you simply want that letter, but this also allows you to type in other accented characters easily.

Answer (score 1):

More info at these links:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umlaut_(diacritic)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code

http://fsymbols.com/alt-codes

Comment: Note: It's not an umlaut ...

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can find the keystroke combinations on a Windows machine from the Character Map applet.  It's located by default in Start | Accessories | System Tools.  Click on a character and you get the keystroke combination in the bottom-right corner of the tool.  You can also just copy/paste from there for infrequently used characters.