# Typing an ellipsis on Windows

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, typing

Occasionally I find the need to include an ellipsis in my writing. I could just use three periods, but that's bad typography. Is there a way to insert `&hellip;` just using the keyboard? Similar to how you can insert `&mdash;` by holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and pressing <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> on the numberpad. Is there a similar combination for inserting an ellipsis?

Comment: Ellipsis Related: [Cannot use Alt code for Unicode character insertion any more](http://superuser.com/questions/509330/cannot-use-alt-code-for-unicode-character-insertion-any-more)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In Windows it's <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> on the numberpad.

Comment: What can one do without a numberpad, commonly missing on laptops. Nevermind, https://superuser.com/questions/372748/how-to-input-special-characters-w-o-numpad

Comment: I would upvote this answer, but active participation on StackExchange feels too much like tacit endorsement of their terrible treatment of one of their most valued contributors. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336526/stack-overflow-is-doing-me-ongoing-harm-its-time-to-fix-it

Comment: @Screenack, on many laptops there is a special key that makes a part of the keyboard act as a numberpad.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Office applications (Word, Outlook, Excel, etc.) accept the following shortcut:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

(found by my pleasantly surprised cat)