# ALT Codes work in Word... but inproper anywhere else

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard

I have a strange problem: I am using Windows XP and ALT Codes (e.g. ALT+0151 for emdash) work in Microsoft Word, but not anywhere else (e.g. Editor). In all applications but word any ALT Code only results in the last pressed digit (e.g. ALT+0151 results in ☺ which is the same as ALT+1) no matter how fast or slow I type.

I think this is a very odd problem --- does anyone have an idea about why this might be? I realize that this might be a tricky question without more specifications, but this is all I know. ☺

Thank you for any ideas you might have!

Comment: Make sure you have numlock on ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply David. I have numlock on... else I wouldn't get the ☺ symbol for any ALT code ending with 1. :)

Comment: Try hitting ctrl, shift and alt a few times (seperately). Sometimes the keyboard can get stuck in a strange state (has happened to me a few times)

Comment: What happens if you close word? Have you restarted your computer?

Comment: I tried rebooting, closing word, even a different keyboard. This is not a hardware problem. The ALT codes only work in Word. In all other applications only the last digital of the ALT code seems to be accounted for.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas :/

Comment: I think I found a related post...
http://superuser.com/questions/509330/cannot-use-alt-code-for-unicode-character-insertion-any-more