# How can one input a Unicode character by its hex/decimal value on Dell Latitude e6420 model laptops?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, unicode

The solution is to input Unicode characters (see here: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F300.pdf, 1f36c for example) with the keyboard of a Dell Latitude e6420 which, a quick Google image search tells us looks like:

[image]. Notice in the picture how the orange keys <kbd>Fn</kbd> allows access to a "numeric keypad" type function.

Question then is: how can one input the Unicode character 1F36C using the keyboard only?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/47420/insert-unicode-characters-via-the-keyboard

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you type Unicode characters using hexadecimal codes?](http://superuser.com/questions/13086/how-do-you-type-unicode-characters-using-hexadecimal-codes)

Comment: shouldn't be duplicates when Re is made to specific models of laptop since key combinations will differ between models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Windows (XP or later), hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key then type `+1F36C`. To enter the `+` sign on this keyboard, you will hold down the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and the <kbd>? /</kbd> key simultaneously (while still holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key).

If this does not work, sometimes a registry key must be changed (regedit). Under `HKEY_Current_User/Control Panel/Input Method`, set `EnableHexNumpad` to "1". If you have to add it, set the type to be `REG_SZ`. It should then work (after a reboot).

If none of this works, you can use the standard decimal value <kbd>Alt</kbd> code, which is to hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> while typing 127836 (the decimal value of 0x1F36C).

Comment: Doing as you've said, holding down the Fn AND alt AND pressing the ?/+ key ... windows makes a ding sound. Tests results same before/after regedit.

Comment: @jhstuckey Try my last resort, just added it to response.

Comment: @jhstuckey also note that you must reboot for any registry changes to take effect, so that may be why it didn't work....

Comment: After reboot, \ is produced by alt + 127836 (but note you have to use the Fn key w/ orange numbers). Pressing Fn + alt + /? gives a windows "ding" after reboot.

Comment: Correction, it gives a windows ding when I try to type in *this* comment box, but in other areas it gives me a rectangle (w/ the test unicode value).

Comment: @jhstuckey you don't enter a `+` sign with the decimal value, just the number....

Comment: I just did it successfully on Windows 7 with the Alt decimal code. Not sure what else to tell you.

Comment: º was produced for 127911, and \ --- disregard my comment about entering a +, that was an id10t error.