# Insert Unicode characters via the keyboard in Windows 10 on a laptop without a numeric keypad

Tags: windows-10, unicode, special-characters

I have already read this answer [Insert Unicode characters via the keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/47420/insert-unicode-characters-via-the-keyboard). However I have tried that on Windows 10 and it didn't seem to change anything. Considering that the solution was from back in 2009, perhaps there is something else that needs to be done in order to get it to work. Any pointers would be helpful.

EDIT:

It seems that for this to work, you have to type the "+" key on the numeric keypad. What about those on a laptop and no numeric keypad?

Comment: [Assign](http://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key) unused key as the "+" key

Comment: #2 from the accepted answer you linked to (EnableHexNumpad) works fine in Windows 10. As for the "+" key, most laptops come with an [embedded numeric keypad](http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/320805-hidden-numeric-keypad-cursors-your-laptop.html) but how to switch to it is manufacturer and model dependent.