# How can type letter "kappa" in Microsoft word 2010 with this font?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, greek

it sure looks weird but I am trying to type a specific type of kappa in my article.
 If I use the kappa available in "Equation" and "symbols" in "Insert" tab it looks exactly the same as small letter "k". But I want my "kappa" to have a higher arch and a shorter vertical thingy :D just like this image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would probably start here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kappa

It contains a list of all the unicodes for kappa. The one you are looking for might be closest to this:  U+1D73F

As to that exact font - it would be a typographers design for one of those Unicodes. There are no other valid characters. So next up is some digging as whatthefont.com could not match it.

Do you have a few more letters to check? Send them over to that site and get the right font to match your Unicode character.

Once you have the font you will need to type the Unicode character in Word. Typing in Unicode in Windows and Word is fun. A few utilities might help:

http://www.fileformat.info/tool/unicodeinput/index.htm
https://github.com/mjvh80/SymWin

For more info see this superuser entry:
[Insert Unicode characters via the keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/47420/insert-unicode-characters-via-the-keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

`Euclid Symbol Italic` font is not available in my MS work 2010 but the image given below I received from [this](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mathtype/euclid-symbol/) link.

[image]

Comment: I think the reason I could not type that specific kappa was due licensing. Do you know where can I buy that font on the website? since it is not for sale