# How can I get "WHITE SMILING FACE (U+263A)" with the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

How can I get "WHITE SMILING FACE (U+263A)" with the keyboard?

Comment: Duplicate of, among others, "How do you type Unicode characters using hexadecimal codes?" at http://superuser.com/questions/13086/how-do-you-type-unicode-characters-using-hexadecimal-codes

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate. Since the "white smiling face" is also an ASCII character, which is simpler to type than unicode ones.

Comment: Code page 437 is hardly ASCII.  Less so than, say, ISO 8859-1.

Comment: @Arjan van Bentem agree, it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Windows you can:

<kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> : ☺

**But the number must be from the Numeric Keypad**

You can also:

Left Alt + 2 : ☻
Left Alt + 3 : ♥
Left Alt + 4 : ♦
Left Alt + 5 : ♣
Left Alt + 6 : ♠
Left Alt + 7 : •
Left Alt + 8 : ◘
Left Alt + 9 : ○
Left Alt + 10 : ◙
Left Alt + 11 : ♂
Left Alt + 12 : ♀
Left Alt + 13 : ♪
Left Alt + 14 : ♫
Left Alt + 15 : ☼
Left Alt + 16 : ►

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu (and variants thereof, like LinuxMint) you can enter Unicode values by pressing Ctrl+Shift+u followed by the Unicode value and Enter, for example:

Ctrl+Shift+u 263a  yields:

Text: ☺
Screenshot: [image]

You might be able to couple this with AutoHotkey for easier input, or *possible* input in Windows.

Comment: Seems to me this answer fits very well at "How do you type Unicode characters using hexadecimal codes?" (http://superuser.com/questions/13086/how-do-you-type-unicode-characters-using-hexadecimal-codes)

Comment: Thank you, Arjan. I've migrated this answer over there. I wouldn't object to marking this "duplicate" if enough believe it is such.

Comment: ...although, my guess would be that the question's author here didn't know how to phrase the question such that the other would show up in the "Similar questions" list in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. (And closed questions don't disappear, it's just to keep the answers in one place.)

Answer (score 0):

its really fun to make the white smiley and it's really easy once you know how to make a white smiley. All you have to do is click the left alt and click the number 1 one the number pad thing.☺ and there you go, you get a white smiley.