# How to type special characters in Linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard, unicode

In windows there is possibility to type from keyboard special signs by holding alt key and typing a few numbers, that depends on with sign you want to use. Does it work with linux in the same way?

Comment: in windows, this does only work for ascii-codes, right? how to do so for unicode-characters?

Comment: frabra, not all applications support unicode input such way. But rather often starting number with zero helps, i. e. type Alt + 08212 for M-dash, instead of Alt + 8212.

Comment: @FranBran you need to [enable hex numpad](https://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm) and then you can input any Unicode characters

Comment: @Smylic that won't work for most applications because the decimal Alt-code will be modulo 256. You have to use hex numpad

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you type Unicode characters using hexadecimal codes?](https://superuser.com/questions/13086/how-do-you-type-unicode-characters-using-hexadecimal-codes) (While most of the answers are about Windows, a couple are about Linux.)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> followed by the code in **hex**. (You only need to hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> while typing the code)

Comment: john, do you know what supplies this functionality?  i haven't heard of it before.  where does it work, on the console?  Ubuntu's defaults in GNOME?  thx.

Comment: found a similar source (minus the `u`, just hold down `Ctrl+Shift`) for "works in GNOME", and a method for VIM that uses the `u` but not the `Shift`.

Comment: Thx, works for me. In Ubuntu's terminal (under X), I'm able to type Ctrl+Shift+U, let up all 3, and then type 66 followed by Space and I end up with "f" which is the correct character for 66 in UTF-8. It didn't work from tty1 (control-alt-F1 - non-graphical terminal) though.

Comment: Any solution to KDE?

Comment: I use `Compose` (mapped as Right-Ctrl), which should work in all DEs since it is provided by X.  `Compose " A` => `ä`, `Compose g p i` => "π", etc

Comment: for example: (1.) `ctrl+shift+u` (2.) `hold down: ctrl + shift` and type `2022` (3.) gets you: `•`

Comment: Hint 1: For figuring out hex codes (of characters you havbe in your clipboard) go to the [ishida unicode converter](https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/)

Comment: This might not work because of keyboard shortcut conflict, see [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1538171/490855).

Comment: On my system, Manjaro with Gnome in the year 2023, it took a while to figure out how it works: Press Ctrl-Shift-u, an underlined u appears, release all buttons, then press the hex code like 2022 (the hex code is also displayed underlined, and then press Enter. Then the desired character will replace the code _u2022_ → •

Answer (score 82):

X uses something called the [compose key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key).  By pressing <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>some key</kbd>, <kbd>some key</kbd>… in sequence, you can input characters.  I have my compose key set to <kbd>Menu</kbd>; to type a `©` (copyright symbol), I would use <kbd>Menu</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>.

A full list of X compose key combinations can be found [online](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libX11/plain/nls/en_US.UTF-8/Compose.pre) (200 KiB), or locally in `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`.

In Gnome, the compose key can be set by going to Preferences → Keyboard → Layouts tab → Layout Options → Compose key position.

Comment: How does the "memorize unicode code points" answer have twice as many upvotes as the compose key? Insanity.

Comment: Perfect. Without GNOME, the compose key can be set through `setxkbmap`. For example, `$ setxkbmap -option 'compose:menu'` will set the "menu" key (between Alt Gr and right Ctrl on my keyboard) as the compose key.

Comment: @mehaase Because, on my laptop, there is no available key for me to map as Compose. So I'll take an imperfect answer over the elegant one.

Comment: Cliff, what strange laptop is that?  I have a tiny laptop which has a "menu" key (which virtuallinux uses as Compose key, as do I).  It doesn't have a free unused key?  No "Windows" key you don't need in Linux anyway?  Weird.

Comment: @Cliff, I managed to set it to “3rd level of Left Ctrl”, so spare key required; I hope you can find something that works for you.

Comment: How the heck do I do this one? `<dead_greek> <W>`

Answer (score 39):

Inputting Unicode characters in Linux varies.  The [UTF-8 and Unicode FAQ](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html) has a section containing [different input methods](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#input):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> `[unicode in hex]` is defined in [ISO 14755](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/volatile/ISO-14755.pdf) and implemented by GTK2+, and works in GNOME-Terminal and other applications.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd> `[unicode in hex]` works in VIM.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+`[unicode in decimal using numpad digits]` works at the console providing your environment is properly configured to expect UTF-8 (via LOCALE or LANG environment variables). ([unicode_start manpage](http://www.kbd-project.org/manpages/man1/unicode_start.1.html)).

Other methods you could use:

- Cut-n-paste characters from a small input file containing the characters you want.
- Use `xmodmap` to remap keys in X (see the FAQ link above for examples).

Comment: (I removed the UTF8 tag you added to the question, as that is actually an encoding, which is not used when typing a character.)

Comment: +1 for including VIM. I was curious how to do this in Intellij with VIM keybindings.

Comment: I can confirm that alt-numpad works for me in ubuntu 12.04's tty1 console (control-alt-F1) with $LANG=en_US.utf8
The codes are decimal, not hex though, so instead of 66 (hex) for "f", I hold Alt, type 102, let Alt up and out pops "f".

Comment: Sad world we live in when people have all but forgotten about the beauty of Compose.

Comment: So, none of these seem to work in Cinnamon :-(

Comment: +1 for the ISO reference and link. It is good to know this has been standardised.

Answer (score 8):

The Linux console also supports compose keys (The compose key is often <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>AltGr</kbd> or <kbd>PrintScrn</kbd>) - see [How to define a Compose Key in terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44478) on the Unix and Linux Stack Exchange for details.

Answer (score 8):

Alternative way: 
Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> followed by the code in **hex** and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Unlike the accepted answer tells, do not hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> while typing the code. Otherwise it may not work because it may conflict with some shortcut key of the application you are using, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> in your terminal emulator. That may be a bug though.

This way works at least with xfce4-terminal, gnome-terminal, lxterminal, libreoffice, mousepad, chromium-browser and firefox.

Comment: Upvoted. Though I found that this works on Xubuntu in the Terminal Emulator, but not in editors -- nevertheless, one can always type it in the terminal using this method, then copy-paste. Acceptable if you don't use extra-special characters all the time.

Comment: On most systems I need to hold ctrl+shift like in the accepted answer, but there are some on which your answer is right. Maybe it depends on the X input method? I think you should merge your answers into one, especially when you find out when to use which answer.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Cinnamon. After pressing Ctrl+Shift+u I get an underlined u, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

There's a better method for both Linux and Windows than using alt-key codes that doesn't require you to remember any codes. It's described in detail [here](https://brushingupscience.com/2015/12/28/add-any-symbol-without-leaving-the-keyboard/).

The gist is that you use AutoHotKey (Windows) or AutoKey (Linux). Both run in the background and accept arbitrary strings as trigger to run a command, which in this case is to send a special character to the clipboard and then paste it to whatever program is currently being used.

The example given has /delta as the trigger (including the forward slash). After typing those six characters, they are deleted and replaced with a δ.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a US key user and need to type special characters infrequently, I recommend switching your keyboard layout to the "us(altgr-intl)" variation-- that's XKB notation. Your keyboard will work normally unless you hold the right Alt key, also known "AltGr", then you will mostly be able to access the extra characters shown in blue here:
[image: US International Keyboard Layout]

I say "mostly" because that's a screenshot of the main US International layout. I found the details of the "altgr-intl" variation defined in this file on Arch Linux:  `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`: Here are the differences defined there:

```
// five dead keys moved into level3:

  ┊key <TLDE> { [    grave, asciitilde,  dead_grave,   dead_tilde      ] };
  ┊key <AC11> { [apostrophe,quotedbl,    dead_acute,   dead_diaeresis  ] };

// diversions from the MS Intl keyboard:

  ┊key <AE01> { [        1, exclam,      onesuperior,  exclamdown      ] };
  ┊key <AD04> { [        r, R,           ediaeresis,   Ediaeresis      ] };
  ┊key <AC07> { [        j, J,           idiaeresis,   Idiaeresis      ] };
  ┊key <AB02> { [        x, X,           oe,           OE              ] };
  ┊key <AB04> { [        v, V,           registered,   registered      ] };

// onequarter etc (not in iso8859-15) moved to get three unshifted deadkeys:

  ┊key <AE06> { [        6, asciicircum, dead_circumflex, onequarter    ] };
  ┊key <AE07> { [        7, ampersand,   dead_horn,       onehalf       ] };
  ┊key <AE08> { [        8, asterisk,    dead_ogonek,     threequarters ] };
```

This alternate layout doesn't have the additional "dead keys" that the main International layout does.

The four columns in each array are *Regular*, *Shifted*, *AltGr*, *AltGr Shifted*.

So for example to type ¡ I press "<Shift-AltGr-1>".

You can search for an image of the US International layout until you remember the locations of the symbols you need.