# How can I input unicode characters by code point in Xfce (Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, unicode, xfce, input

In Gnome, [entering Shift-Ctrl-U plus hex codes](https://superuser.com/questions/59418/how-to-type-special-characters-in-linux) allows you to enter arbitrary unicode characters (see also [this](https://superuser.com/a/59135/17025). This is supposed to work for any Gtk2 app, but is not working for me in `gnome-terminal` (or any other application) in Xfce (running on Ubuntu Natty). (It's apparently [not currently possible in KDE](https://superuser.com/questions/74763/how-to-type-unicode-characters-in-kde)).

Is there an equivalent way of entering characters in Xfce? Or is there some way of enabling this? Note that I'm not interested in special shortcuts for particular characters; there are some unicode codepoints that I know and would like to use directly...

Comment: Works fine here, even in Terminal.

Comment: Ah, thanks ... will investigate further what's going wrong...

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the default input method was configured as `xim`; switching this using `gnome-control-center` to launch `gnome-language-selector` and select `ibus` resolved the issue.