# How to write in a command in Unicode?

Tags: windows, command-line, unicode

Say I have a file that has an Armenian or Russian name. How can I write that file name in command prompt in order to open it. And not only for this purpose in general I want to know how can I write in terminal with Unicode?

My OS is Vista.

Comment: It's probably less of a hassle to just use copy & paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enter arbitrary unicode anywhere, it's just a question of how cumbersome it might be.

http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm

> **Method 1: Universal**
>
> This method works regardless of any of your language settings, but is the most cumbersome to type.
>
> 1. Press and hold down the <kbd>alt</kbd> key.
> 2. Press the <kbd>+</kbd> key on the numeric keypad.
> 3. Type the hexadecimal unicode value.
> 4. Release the <kbd>alt</kbd> key.

More methods at the above link. And see related SU question:
[How do you type Unicode characters using hexadecimal codes?](https://superuser.com/questions/13086/how-do-you-type-unicode-characters-using-hexadecimal-codes)

Answer (score 0):

Just run `dir` to get the file list. After that copy the needed filename and then paste into the `ren` command. That's the easiest solution, no need to look for the unicode value