# How to input any UTF-8 string as if typed on keyboard from console in Linux/Xorg

Tags: linux, xorg, input

Like in `xte "str ў"`, but with support of all characters.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/13086/how-do-you-type-unicode-characters-using-hexadecimal-codes

Answer (score 1):

GNOME allows you to enter any Unicode codepoint in hex after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>.

Comment: 1. I already know about Ctrl+Shift+U. 2. "From console" also means "scriptable". 3. I want to be able to type it in Qt apps too.