# How to disable Ctrl+Shift+U?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> is a combined shortcut in Eclipse.

But when I press it, it shows up a `u`, just like input with an underline. I guess this shortcut has been declared by Ubuntu, so I can't use it.

I used to solve this problem by typing <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> first.

Is there any better method?

Comment: @Code-Guru: (1) You might have *Locate Pointer* setting turned on in *Universal Access* under *Pointing & Clicking* section. Turn it off to see if it works. (2) This [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/358749/how-to-disable-ctrlshiftu-in-ubuntu-linux/1392682#1392682) below is claimed by some as still working.

Comment: For reference, this causes conflicts with IntelliJ as well. More details: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-112533/Toggle-Case-Ctrl-Shift-U-not-working-under-Gnome-Linux

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Found a way to unbind it on Ubuntu 13.10.

Go to **Language Support** on **System Settings** and change the **Keyboard input method system** to `none`

Then restart the system or just log out and log in.

Comment: Just logging out and back in works for me.

Answer (score 147):

### Problem

The problem is that with the "Ibus" input method, "Ctrl-shift-u" is by default configured to the "Unicode Code Point" shortcut. You can try this: Type ctrl-shift-u, then an (underlined) u appears. If you then type a unicode code point number in hex (e.g. 21, the ASCII/unicode CP for !) and press enter, it is replaced with the corresponding character.

[image: Example of ctr-shift-u]

### Solution (GUI)

This shortcut can be changed or disabled using the `ibus-setup` utility:

1. Run `ibus-setup` from the terminal (or open IBus Preferences).
2. Go to “Emoji”.
3. Next to “Unicode code point:”, click on the three dots (i.e. `...`).
4. In the dialog, click “Delete”, then “OK”.
5. Close the IBus Preferences window.

[image: Ibus preferences window]

### Solution (CLI)

If you want to script this, the Unicode hotkey can also be disabled using `gsettings` like this:

```shell
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji unicode-hotkey "@as []"
```

Comment: @Phill Indeed, for me, too, this no longer works. Even though it clearly should. It doesn’t seem to work in either 19.10 or 20.04, unfortunately.

Comment: @kleinfreund I figured out a way by renaming the IBUS daemon `mv /bin/ibus-daemon /bin/ibus-daemon.bak` and rebooting. This killed it for me finally.

Comment: `Ubuntu 18.04.4` ibus-setup has emoji shortcuts, but no `unicode chortcuts` settings : (

Comment: @Neurotransmitter For me, these steps unfortunately no longer work. I also tried to set the keyboard input method system to “none”, but the two shortcuts are still active when I type in, for example, a VS Code editor window.

Comment: Tried again this solution and it worked. It seems that the linked patch was required to make the solution work https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1885914

Comment: For this to work on Ubuntu 20.04, you will need to [configure it to use ibus](https://superuser.com/a/1392682/470805). The default IM module is `gtk-im-context-simple` which intercepts Ctrl+Shift+U on its own (and I don't know if there is a way to disable it)

Comment: @Conrado Why would I want to mess with something as internal as this? I don’t even know what ibus is to begin with. I just want use a keyboard shortcut that is being hogged by something else that I don’t want to use.

Comment: @kleinfreund Chill dude, maybe complain to the Ubuntu developers, I'm just sharing what worked for me. Also I got the link wrong, [this is how you configure Ubuntu to use ibus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/262220)

Comment: Validated with Ubuntu 21.10 to work

Comment: This worked for me and should be the accepted answer, as it clearly explains what the Ctrl+Shift+U does on Ubuntu and how to disable it.

Comment: Validated with Ubuntu 22.04 to Work

Comment: Tried the GUI solution on ZorinOS 16.2 (based on Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.15), and it worked flawlessly. Didn't even have to log out and back in again. Just removed the shortcuts and it instantly worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

## Ubuntu 18.04 Solution

@ShmulikA's answer was close, but unfortunately, selecting "None" did not work for me. I can confirm the process below works in 18.04 as of April 2019.

1. Open **Search** using <kbd>Super</kbd> key (aka <kbd>WIN</kbd> for folks like me)
2. Type "language support" and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

[image]

3. Click the **Keyboard input method system** dropdown menu and select **XIM**

[image]

4. Click **Close**
5. Reboot

When I logged back in, I was able to set <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> as a shortcut in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: This unlocks the key binding but messes up some applications. Dconf Editor is very glitchy now and DBeaver became unusable. How hard can it be to disable a fraking shortcut, Ubuntu?

Comment: After changing the input method, gedit and other gnome text fields had "transparent" background bug. To fix that execute `rm ~/.xinputrc` and reboot. Solution from https://askubuntu.com/a/840073/28004

Comment: @Brown I just found out that after removing the .xinputrc file the ctrl+shift+u doesn't work again. I am trying other solutions, however without success so far.

Comment: I have continued VERY bad experiences with setting xim under Ubuntu 16, 20 and 22 (among other thing an ever flickering LibreOffice). I don't have a sound explanation, but returning to IBus (which is the installation default) fixed that.

Answer (score 12):

I use Ubuntu 18.10 and had trouble in a particular app (Intellij Idea).

[In this askUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1118941/685872), Kayvan Tehrani shows a setting that works for me in that setting. Set the XMODIFIERS to an empty string before running your application:

```
export XMODIFIERS=""
myapp.sh
```

In my case, myapp.sh was idea.sh, and I added the line inside the file:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# IntelliJ IDEA startup script.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
#
export XMODIFIERS=""
...
```

This way, my desktop shortcut still works.

XMODIFIERS apparently changes the way xim and ibus works, and when it's cleared, it disables the CTRL-SHIFT-U combo, allowing it to filter into the current app.

Comment: Helpful, but with the caveat that it also disables the compose key and any .XCompose shortcuts you might have set up (at least on Linux Mint 19.3---YMMV).

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE="gtk-im-context-simple"
```

and then run Eclipse from the same shell. Or if that doesn't work,

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"
```

(This test only works entering running the export command and then Eclipse from the same shell command line, it won't change anything if you use a desktop shortcut or the Applications menu, or run Eclipse from a new shell.)

If either test works, you can make the change system-wide by adding it to `/etc/environment`, or per-user in `~/.gnomerc`. (The `export` command doesn't go in those files, just a new line with `GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"` or `GTK_IM_MODULE="gtk-im-context-simple"`.)

It sounds like this behavior comes from GTK's input mappings as described [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkIMContext.html#GtkIMContext.description).

> ... This is called preediting, and an input method may provide feedback about this process by displaying the intermediate composition states as preedit text. For instance, the default GTK+ input method implements the input of arbitrary Unicode code points by holding down the Control and Shift keys and then typing “U” followed by the hexadecimal digits of the code point. When releasing the Control and Shift keys, preediting ends and the character is inserted as text. Ctrl+Shift+u20AC for example results in the € sign.

GTK is used by a whole lot of common apps in Ubuntu, including Eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

Changing the input method as PutzKipa explains actually fixes the problem.

However, I've failed to find any configuration panel under KDE ubuntu 14.04 to do the job, and the standard *im-config* utility seems broken. I finally succeeded by creating a file **~/.xinputrc** that contains a single line:

```
run_im xim
```

then logout/login. This chooses *xim* as the input method (*ibus* is the default). If you remove your **~/.xinputrc**, then *im-config* can  list the input methods available, even if it fails to select one.

Answer (score 4):

#### Ubuntu 18.04

Running into this problem on Ubuntu 18.04, I've tried all suggestion above, but unfortunately none of them worked. I ended up uninstalling the `ibus` package.

#### Background / sidenotes

I tried to disable IBus using

1. the `Language Support` menu
2. `im-config` (configures `~/.xinputrc`)
3. `sudo im-config` (configures `/etc/X11/xinit/xinputrc`)

I noticed however that no matter what config I tried, the ibus daemon was running everytime after I had rebooted.

Answer (score 3):

## Ubuntu 14.04/18.04 Solution

recently upgrade to 18.04 and fight my way to solve this issue.

1. open **search** using `super` key
2. go to **language support**
3. click **Keyboard input method system** dropdown menu and choose **none**

[image: Language Support Menu]

4. **dont forget** to click - **apply system wide**
5. close the window (wont activate until you do)
6. reboot (logout might be enough)

Credit goes to [reverse issue](https://askubuntu.com/a/1044481) on askubuntu - for some reason someone wants to enable this shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

**For Ubuntu 18.04.**

I struggled with this problem for two days. I tried all the methods listed here earlier. And it looks like I came up with a solution. But it is very unstable and has bugs.

The basic idea is this: in the system settings you can specify the command that is started by the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> key combination.

*Note: if you specify `false` as the command, the combination will not work at all.*

However, we can specify the path to the script as the command, in which we will simulate pressing the same key combination.

To simulate keystrokes, I tried the `xdotool` (`apt install xdotool`) and the `xte` (`apt install xautomation`).
Both options were unstable. However, `xte` turned out to be more flexible for me.

**Example with `xte`**

- Create a file `/home/username/shortcut.sh`
- Add permission to execute: `chmod u+x /home/username/shortcut.sh`
- Specify the path to the script as a command for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> key combination in the keyboard settings

Here is an example script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Make a small delay in order to have time to release the keys.
sleep 0.2

# Simulate the release of just pressed keys, if they are still pressed.
xte 'keyup u' 'keyup Shift_L' 'keyup Control_L'

# Hack: Caps_Lock is used so that the system does not intercept this combination.
# You can try to remove it if it hinders you.
xte 'key Caps_Lock'

# Simulate pressing a key combination
xte 'keydown Shift_L' 'keydown Control_L' 'key u'

# Simulate releasing a key combination
xte 'keyup Shift_L' 'keyup Control_L'

# Restore Caps_Lock to the previous state.
xte 'key Caps_Lock'
```

I tested this in PhpStorm 2018.2 EAP Build #PS-182.3458.35 and I can say that it works, but with some caveats:

- this works slowly (on my rather old PC)
- during the execution of the script, it is better not to press any keys
- sometimes it may not work
- sometimes it can enter an infinite loop. Therefore, it's better to add a check to the script that the script is already running.

In general, if you do not often use this combination, then this solution may suit you.

But, probably, someone will come up with a better and more stable solution.

I hope this idea will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the system for entering non-Latin characters provided by [iBus](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IBus), uninstall it and reboot:

```bsh
$ sudo apt remove ibus
$ sudo reboot
```

Comment: And if you have trouble removing ibus because zoom depends on it, see this page for how to remove the (incorrect) dependency from zoom to ibus: https://hashman.ca/zoom/

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions here worked for me. In the end I had to disable the daemon completely.

`mv /bin/ibus-daemon /bin/ibus-daemon.bak`

Then rebooted my computer.

It still does the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> unicode thing in Terminal and Firefox.

But no longer does it in VS Code, Jetbrains Rider, DataGrip, or NotepadQQ.

Answer (score 0):

To change it on terminal ([instead of GUI](https://superuser.com/a/1392682/500826)), for example to <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + **Super** + u</kbd>:

```sh
# Get
gsettings get org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji unicode-hotkey

# Set   
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji unicode-hotkey "['<Control><Super><Shift>u']"
```