# How to disable Ctrl+Shift+U in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-18.04

How to disable <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> shortcut in Ubuntu 18.04?

Solution from [answer](https://superuser.com/a/670910/916256) no longer works in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: It's better to have the old question updated, not to post a new question for each new release of an OS. I have placed a bounty on the other question to draw new answers.

Comment: really the solution mentioned in "already has an answer" post doesnt work.

Comment: found solution here https://superuser.com/a/1344949/929259

Comment: No @ShmulikA it doesn't work.

Comment: Another solution: https://superuser.com/a/1392682/736624