# How to disable Ctrl+Shift+U in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, language, hotkeys, case, emoji

ctrl+shift+u is a change case, to set lowercase, but it conflicts with annother command, that produces a underlined ''u'', which produces an emoji when combined with a number.

It annoyed me so much because when I am working with a text editor in Chromium I need to use this shortcut but I can't.

I've tried everything, I removed the ibus package but the error persists. I will type capslock first the command to avoid this error for now, but is there any better method?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/670910/141399 already answered :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Ctrl+Shift+U in Ubuntu Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/358749/how-to-disable-ctrlshiftu-in-ubuntu-linux)

Comment: these solutions doesn't works, I changed the Keyboard input method system to none and the problem continues
when I change to XIM solves the problem but I loose the accents of my keyboard
I removed the ibus and I really don't understand why but the problem persists

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1392682/150403) worked for me on 20.04.

Comment: @Code-Guru this answer does not work for me, and uninstalling ibus does not works either