# How to identify/remove keyboard shortcut by the key combination (issue with ctrl-shift-u and ctrl-.)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, kde

I've some unwanted keyboard shortcuts on my kubuntu 21.10 installation that appear global and are therefore interfering with other programs.  Since both give somewhat odd behavior it's hard for me to trace the issue.

The two that I'm currently having issues with are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> (e.g. the kate shortcut for convert-to-lowercase), which gives an underlined-"u" which waits for additional input and then disappears when I type something else in.  Similarly, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> yields an underlined "e" in any text input region that then adds in other underlined text if I continue to type, but disappears if I push Escape.

Neither of these appear to be in the System shortcuts or custom shortcuts menus.  While I can search by action, there does not appear to be a way to search by key-combination-for-shortcut.  How can I figure out what is causing these issues?

I'd note that I didn't have this issue with previous versions of KDE; the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> wasn't an issue until ~20.04, and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> appeared with a recent update.

Comment: There is an [old post](https://superuser.com/questions/358749/how-to-disable-ctrlshiftu) from 2011 about disabling ctrl-shift-u. Does it help?

Comment: That's exactly the problem; apparently ctrl-period is the emoji set up.  I swear I searched for ctrl-shift-u first and found nothing.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the searchbar in the shortcut settings to find shortcuts by their corresponding keys.

[image]

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks.  That seems to search for normal shortcuts, but the ones I mentioned have the same abnormal behavior when I try them in that search bar(?!).  Your answer should have solved the problem but didn't -- how should I edit my question?  Unfortunately I don't have the rep to upvote

Comment: @RiseoverRun as you can see in the screenshot, you can enter the keyboard combination in words, e.g. "Ctrl+t". I realized that the shortcut is for entering unicode and you cannot find it in the system settings. I'm sorry that I couldn't help with your problem, but I'll leave this answer anyways