# How to type a caron char with qwerty keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, special-characters, qwerty

How to type a caron char with a qwerty keyboard?
I really need a blank space with this carot. I used the following instructions with no success. The opposite char, the carot, is printed on my keyboard keys.

I need it to work at least on Google Chrome.

[image]

Comment: I use a Catalan keyboard layout and I can type the Carot char over a space, like that: ^^^. I just need the updown of that -> the Carot.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/q/413879/52492

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a caron for your cutting and pasting pleasure: ̌

You may combine it as you wish: ľ ǐ ǩ ě   ť ȟ ǐ š .

Here's a spare: ̌

Comment: LoL, but it's a solution. Thank you !!

Comment: It seems that without modifying the registry or changing the IME, there's no good way to do this in Windows. Probably the best solution is to use Wordpad and the Alt-X method in RedGrittyBrick's answer, then cut/paste the character into the application you need it in.

Answer (score 5):

> **How to type a caron char with querty keyboard?**

In Wordpad, type a **space**, then type **030C**

[image]

and then press **Alt+X**

[image]

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caron#Unicode
and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: ALT+268 works but I don't want the C

Comment: @senyortoni: But what happens when you try what I actually suggested in my answer?

Comment: It works. But I want to use it in Chrome for example.

Comment: @senyortoni: Sorry, I didn't see that mentioned in you question.

Comment: I didn't specify. I'm sorry but your answer is right.

Comment: Does ALT+780 work?

Comment: @ David Schwartz. No I get the same as ALT+268. This: ♀

Answer (score 1):

Chrome OS...
The caron is AltGr & > then the letter applied to...
ǎčďěǧȟǐǰǩľňǒřšťǔž

**AltGr** + **> v** gets ǚ

**AltGr** + **.** *letter* gets dotted such as ȧ

**AltGr** + **@** *letter* gets Hungarian Umlaut such as ő

**AltGr** + **#** *letter* gets ¯ macron, such as ā...

**AltGr** + **'** *letter* gets acute accent such as á, but so does **AltGr** + **a** - many letters get this

**AltGr** + **"** *letter* gets Umlaut/Derisis such as ä

**AltGr** + **6** **letter** gets careted/circonflex such as â

**AltGr** + **7** *letter* adds a hook, such as ơ ư

**AltGr** + **`** **letter** get accents ague such as à

**AltGr** + **~** **letter** get tildes such as ã,

øØ are **AltGr** + **l** or **AltGr** + **L**

åÅ çÇ ñÑ ðÐ and þÞ are **AltGr** + **w*/*W**/**c**/**C**/**n**/**N**/**d**/**D**/**t**/**T**

Answer (score 0):

Just install [KbdKaz 500](http://www.omega-com.pl/kbdkaz.htm). Using this keyboard, you can insert caron ^ by pressing AltGr+6 and then space.

Comment: That's the caret character, not the caron. Caron points down, caret points up.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caron#Unicode), it's part of Latin Extended-A. Below is the shortcut, if you use it frequently.

[image]