# How can I type Alt codes without a 10-key?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to input special characters w/o numpad?](https://superuser.com/questions/372748/how-to-input-special-characters-w-o-numpad)

On keyboards without the 10-key numeric pad, is it possible to type alt-key codes? I know some laptops have a 10-key overlay that, but besides those, how can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant use codes like Alt+123 but you can use other input methods.

As I wrote in [a recent answer](https://superuser.com/a/463867/52492), some applications allow you to type the hex value of a character and into a document and to then convert that sequence into a single Unicode characters by pressing Alt+X afterwards.