# How to type directly with keyboard the U+200C character?

Tags: keyboard, character-encoding, special-characters, characters, alt-code

How to type **directly** with keyboard the **U+200C** character in **Notepad or other places**... in Windows **8.1**? (**without** depending on a certain font)

I don't want to copy and paste ways.
I don't want any complicated ways.
I just want something like **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>###</kbd>** for typing U+200**C** Directly at any text area in windows **8.1** **without** depending to a certain font. Just like <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>129</kbd> for U+200**B**.

(I do not need <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>129</kbd>, That's for U+200**B**. I need U+200**C**)

the U+200**C** character name is: ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER (ZWNJ)

Here is the U200C character info:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner
- https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm

Comment: Tempted to close as duplicate of https://superuser.com/a/59458/1686

Comment: I upvoded @grawity, but went playing... `Alt`+`+` will immediately insert an equation into Word (thus not suitable)... and converting `0x200B` / `0x200C` to decimal and typing `Alt`+`8203` results in ♂/♀ in Chrome, but quite possibly the characters you're after in Word... Sadly not a stable interface. Additionally copy/pasting the characters from Word doesn't work.

Comment: "without depending to a certain font" that's not possible. If a font doesn't have that character defined you are out of luck.

Comment: Alt+129 gives ü in every place I've tried it. Can you clarify how you got Alt+129 to give you U200B?

Comment: Alt+129 (ZERO WIDTH SPACE): worked every place like notepad or even work here in this reply text. But I need an alt code for **ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER**. aslo, if font is necessary so thats ok. (Arial or some other default fonts.) so how to do this WITH a certain font.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is here.  If you know how to enter the code for U200B, wouldn't you enter the appropriate code for U200C the same way?  Is the issue not knowing what code to enter, not knowing how to enter it, entering it doesn't reliably give you the desired character, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

To enter *ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER (ZWNJ)* or U+200C in Windows, while your keyboard is in Persian or Arabic Do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0157</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>. That's it.

I Hope it Can Help You.

Answer (score 1):

You must enable [Hex numpad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code#Transition_to_Unicode) by creating a registry key named `EnableHexNumpad` with type `REG_SZ` in `HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method`, set its value to 1 then reboot. After that you can type the character as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>numpad+</kbd>, <kbd>Unicode value</kbd> (Alt+<kbd>+200C</kbd> in your case)

In some word processing apps like MS Word, Wordpad, Libre Office... you can just enter the Unicode hex value then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. That means typing `U+200C` or `200C` then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

But to type ZWNJ there's a much easier way. In any standard Windows textboxes just right click (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, or the [Menu key (≣)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key)) > *Insert Unicode control characters* and select the desired character

[image: Notepad insert special characters]

Another way is to create a keyboard layout for your own using [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339) so that you won't need Alt codes for commonly used characters

For more information read

- [How to enter Unicode characters in Microsoft Windows](https://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm)
- [How do you type Unicode characters using hexadecimal codes?](https://superuser.com/q/13086/241386)
- [Insert ASCII or Unicode Latin-based symbols and characters](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0?ocmsassetID=HA010167539&CorrelationId=1ed32bc2-69ca-4bed-b751-4260640e7d09&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still wanting to know but you might be able to do it with AutoHotkey, a programming language for keyboard and mouse hooks allowing you to remap keys and create new key combinations.

After downloading it you should be able to create an AutoHotKey script by right-clicking and clicking new then clicking AutoHotkey script.

After that, you can do:

```
s::
send {U200C}
return
```

which will remap the <kbd>s</kbd> key to the character.

Here you can learn about hot-keys and hot-strings to make it mapped to what you want: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This is really more of a comment, hinting at something the OP could explore, than a solution.  Can you expand this into an actual solution?

Comment: okay @fixer1234

Answer (score 0):

On recent updates of Windows (10 or later), there is a *Standard Persian Keyboard* that inserts ZWNJ by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>. For adding this keyboard on Windows 10, go to `settings -> language` and look at the `Preferred languages` tab. Then, click on `Persian`. You will see the `Options`. Then click on `Add a keyboard` and select *Standard Persian Keyboard*.