# How can you type characters from U+0100 and up with Numpad?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, unicode, numpad

It appears that the Alt + Num shortcuts end at U+00ff (decimal 0255); typing Alt + 0255 yields ÿ which indeed is at U+ff. I have failed in finding out what the system for the hotkeys in excess of decimal 0255 are; they do not match the Unicode charts anymore and adding extra leading zeros do not work either. My question thus is simple: **How can you type characters above U+ff in a Windows environment using Alt plus numpad or some other key combination?** I am already aware that the characters can be created in office suites (LibreOffice, MS Office) using the four-digit Unicode codepoint and pressing Alt + X; what I am searching for is specific ways to type characters using hotkeys only across any (or at least most) Windows environments, where the hotkey can in some way be matched to the Unicode codepoint given for that specific character.

Relevant:

- [How do you type Unicode characters using hexadecimal codes?](https://superuser.com/questions/13086/how-do-you-type-unicode-characters-using-hexadecimal-codes)
  I have tried following the instructions here in the [answer provided by harrymc](https://superuser.com/a/59458/657642), but there is no change in how Windows behaves.

Comment: use hex numpad as already stated in the question you link above. `Alt`+`+0100` will work (note the `+` before the hex code). Did you read the question clearly? Duplicates: [How to type directly with keyboard the U+200C character?](https://superuser.com/q/1410431/241386), [Insert Unicode characters via the keyboard?](https://superuser.com/q/47420/241386)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you type Unicode characters using hexadecimal codes?](https://superuser.com/questions/13086/how-do-you-type-unicode-characters-using-hexadecimal-codes)

Comment: I have edited the registry as per the instructions in https://superuser.com/a/47424/657642, but it fails to work (Alt + Num+ + hexcode). I have tested it in both LibreOffice and Notepad; when I hold Alt and press Num+, I get the incorrect input ding from Windows. Further, when I try to enter a character with letters in it, the behaviour is exactly the same as earlier: it simply opens whichever menu corresponds to that Alt + letter.

Comment: you need to reboot the PC after setting `EnableHexNumpad`

Comment: Yes, I did do that; there is no change. I have even shut it down completely with `shutdown /p`; there is no change.

Comment: did you use the numpad or the number row above? Numbers must be entered with the numpad on the right

Comment: It should be clear from my question that I am using the numpad for entering: ‘How can you type characters above U+ff in a Windows environment using Alt plus numpad or some other key combination?’ As an example, typing Alt + [+] + Num2009 should, were the hex numpad working, U+2009 (&thinsp;); instead it yields the (not unexpected, given it doesn’t work) character ‘┘’ (DOS C9, U+2518).

Answer (score 0):

See the Wikipedia article
[Unicode input - Decimal input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#Decimal_input):

> Some programs running in Microsoft Windows, including recent versions
> of Word and Wordpad, can produce characters from their Unicode code
> points expressed in decimal and entered on the numeric keypad with the
> Alt key held down. For example, the Euro sign € has 20AC as its
> hexadecimal code point, which is 8364 in decimal, so Alt+8364 will
> produce the symbol. Similarly, Alt+120132 produces the double-struck
> character .
>
> Decimal code points in the range 160 –255 must be entered with a
> leading zero (so that the Windows code page is chosen) and furthermore
> the Windows code page must be set to match Unicode (CP1252 must be
> used[a]). For example, Alt+0247 yields a ÷, corresponding to its code
> point, but the character produced by Alt+247 depends on the OEM code
> page, such as Code page 437, and may yield a ≈.
>
> In programs in which Alt codes over 255 do not work, the character
> retrieved usually corresponds to the remainder when the number is
> divided by 256.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question really: "I am already aware that the characters can be created in office suites (LibreOffice, MS Office) using the four-digit Unicode codepoint and pressing Alt + X; what I am searching for is specific ways to type characters using hotkeys only across any (or at least most) Windows environments". Not sure **if** there is any other answer possible, but yeah... It's a bit weird, as most applications use Windows forms and whatnot and should be compatible.

Comment: As do we all, but unfortunately this is the mechanism as provided by Microsoft. You will need to create your own mechanism for the characters that you use. For example, use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to map some unused key combination to your characters, which will work for all the applications.

Comment: Not the original poster, wanted to upvote, but decided to read the question again. I guess AutoHotkey could be part of the answer, although it will still probably rely on key codes - which would lead you back to the original problem.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: With AutoHotkey the character is input directly as if it was typed, the key-codes are not involved, or you could say are bypassed. The problem could only arise if the program doesn't support these characters, for example the Command Prompt with an ANSI code-page.

Comment: Just in case anyone were wondering: I am aware that I haven’t selected this as the answer; the community too seems to agree that it doesn’t seem to actually answer the question. (It should, though, probably, get upvoted as it certainly is ‘useful’ as is said and does show effort.) See the comments by @MaartenBodewes. As stated by said: ‘Not sure if there is any other answer possible […]’ What I think may be a likely thing to come from this then, which could be an accepted answer, is a clear demonstration that there actually is no answer.